# Why do I need two copies of a table in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

SQL beginner here, in my university course we have the following schema.

---

Student (snum: integer, sname: string, major: string, level: string, age: integer)

Class (name: string, meets_at: string, room: string, fid: integer)

Enrolled (snum: integer, cname: string)

Faculty (fid: integer, fname: string, deptid: integer)

---

And one of the exercises is as follows:

**Find the names of all students who are enrolled in two classes that meet at the same time.**

And following is the SQL statement for it

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.SNAME

FROM STUDENT S

WHERE S.SNUM IN (SELECT E1.SNUM

             FROM ENROLLED E1, ENROLLED E2, CLASS C1, CLASS C2

              WHERE E1.SNUM = E2.SNUM AND E1.CNAME <> E2.CNAME

               AND E1.CNAME = C1.NAME

              AND E2.CNAME = C2.NAME AND 

              C1.MEETS_AT = C2.MEETS_AT);
```

In my sub query why is it that two copies of the relations ENROLLED and CLASS are being made use of.

Comment: This makes me sad that universities are still teaching the old style `Join` that was deprecated in like... what?  1993?  Essentially, it's listed twice because it is pulling two different students and each class to each student, and checking to see if the classes are the same.  But this type of `Join` is not easy to read...

Comment: Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: Yes, using ANSI `Join` syntax: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172122(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Pratik Read [what Wikipedia has to say on joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29). (And this query uses DISTINCT where it's not needed.)

Comment: I prefer the ANSI syntax too, but there are enough people still using the old way that I would (reluctantly!) say it's a matter of taste which is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery references the `ENROLMENTS` table twice because it needs to retrieve students who have enrolled more than once, and `CLASSES` twice because it needs to retrieve only students who have enrolled at more than one class.

Consider a simpler query:

```
select C1.NAME, C2.NAME
from   CLASS C1, CLASS C2
where  C1.MEETS_AT = C2.MEETS_AT
and    C1.NAME <> C2.NAME;
```

This would give you a list of classes which meet at the same time. It's necessary to compare the full set of classes against itself, looking for those which have the same `MEETS_AT` time. The last line excludes those classes with the same name.

Your subquery retrieves a list of student numbers for students who have enrolled at more than one class which meets at the same time:

```
SELECT E1.SNUM
  FROM ENROLLED E1, 
       ENROLLED E2, 
       CLASS C1, 
       CLASS C2
 WHERE E1.SNUM = E2.SNUM            -- the same student has enrolled twice
   AND E1.CNAME <> E2.CNAME         -- the enrollments are for difference classes
   AND E1.CNAME = C1.NAME           -- join the class table as C1 for the first enrollment
   AND E2.CNAME = C2.NAME           -- join the class table as C2 for the second enrollment
   AND C1.MEETS_AT = C2.MEETS_AT    -- match the start times for the two enrolled classes
```

Just out of interest the ANSI SQL equivalent of that would be:

```
    select E1.SNUM
      from ENROLLED E1 
inner join ENROLLED E2 on E1.SNUM = E2.SNUM
inner join CLASS C1 on E1.CNAME = C1.NAME
inner join CLASS C2 on E2.CNAME = C2.NAME
     where E1.CNAME <> E2.CNAME
       and C1.MEETS_AT = C2.MEETS_AT
```

Like Siyual, I prefer the ANSI version, but if your university is teaching the old way I suggest you stick with it for now. It works just as well, and plenty of people still use it. Once you understand the concepts, you can choose your preference.

Comment: Only if my teachers taught like this. Thanks lot.It was really really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the table to be declared twice is to compare the table within the same query.

You have to have two copies of the table in order to compare the table against itself.

Your query is looking at E1 and checking it against E2 where the StudentNumber is the same but the name of the class is different.

Then it looks at the C1 table and C2 table and finds the name of the class...then looks to see if the class meets_at is the same.

The reason you need two tables is you cannot compare E1 twice in the same query. There is no way to check the row1 against other rows of the same column in a single query.